# renameTo leaves an empty thumbail after renaming images

Tags: java, android, android-broadcast, file-rename, android-mediascanner

I am trying to rename an image in my app using `renameTo()` but after renaming it leaves an empty thumbnail with old file name and size 0 bytes.  How can I fix it ?

```
private void renameFileAlert(){
        String renameFile = etRenameFile.getText().toString();
        Log.v(TAG, renameFile + " another");
        String filename= al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(fileIndex);

        File oldFilePath = new File(al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(fileIndex));
        Log.v(TAG,oldFilePath.toString());
        x = al_images.get(int_position).getAl_imagepath().get(fileIndex);
        File renamedFile = new File(oldFilePath.getParentFile(), renameFile);
        Log.v(TAG, renamedFile.toString() + " new name");
        boolean renamed = oldFilePath.renameTo(renamedFile);
        if(renamed){
            Log.v(TAG, "rename done");
        } else Log.v(TAG, "failed");
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(PhotosActivity.this,new String[] { renamedFile.toString() }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener()
        {
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
            {
                Log.i("ZAA", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                Log.i("ZAA", "-> uri=" + uri);
            }
        });
    }
```

When media scanner didn't work I tried using scanning using below code but it didn't work too.

```
 public final void notifyMediaStoreScanner(File file) {

        getBaseContext().sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(file)));

    }
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong .Can anyone help me to fix this issue or suggest something ?